# What's the difference between "real frame rate" and "frame rate" in MediaInfo?

Tags: video, framerate, frame

What's the difference between "real frame rate" and "frame rate" in [MediaInfo](https://mediaarea.net/en/MediaInfo)?

[image]

The video was recorded with a Pixel 6 running Android 12 with the [Google Camera](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.GoogleCamera&hl=en_US&gl=US) app configured to record in 4K 30 FPS.

Comment: In this case the difference is 0.085 FPS. Hope this helps. ;)

Comment: The two values are ostensibly the same. https://www.studionetworksolutions.com/video-frame-rate-facts-and-figures/

Answer (score 0):

Frame rate is the frame rate for playback by a player.
Real frame rate is the frame rate used during capture (should have been called "Capture frame rate"), so the one in the reality.

Usually both are same, sometimes not e.g. slow motion etc.